# BTrieve open table not returning all rows

Tags: pervasive, pervasive-sql

For those familiar, DDF files are shared among databases. I have two databases that share the same definition files for Skyline front end. When checking properties, the table x_file shows 513 rows for both but I open (select * from "X_File") one returns correctly and the other does not. I am thinking I need to update schema but not sure how.

Comment: While you can share DDFs, it is not required.  If you use BUTIL -STAT on both of the data files (not through the COntrol Center), do they show the same number of records?

Comment: Thanks for the response mirtheil. It turned out that the DDF needed to be changed to another version and it was able to bull all the files. Your response would have led me to that conclusion faster.